# How to parse multiple JSON strings and convert to dataframe rows using R?

Tags: r, json

Hello community I am new to stackoverflow hope I can write this problem correctly.

I have a R dataframe that looks like this:

```
ID|Product1|Type     |Product_JSON_string
1 | Bread  |Grocery  |{"ID":"1","Product1":"Bread","Type":"Automotive"}
2 | Butter |Grocery  |{"ID":"2","Product1":"Butter","Type":"Grocery"} 
df <- data.frame(ID  = c("1", "2"),
                  Product1 = c("Bread", "Butter"),
                  Type= c("Grocery", "Grocery"),
                  Product_JSON_string= c('{"ID":"1","Product1":"Bread","Type":"Automotive"}',
                                         '{"ID":"2","Product1":"Butter","Type":"Grocery"}'
                                         ))
```

I want to parse the JSON string and see if the JSON string matches the database entries i-e the id, product1 and type are the same in the JSON and the dataframe.
I am able to parse one JSON at a time and convert each variable into a column using this bad piece of code using the jsonlite library.

```
as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(parse_json(minify(db$Product_JSON_string[1]), simplifyVector = FALSE)), nrow=1))
```

However, this is not enough as it only gives me the first row and I am not able vectorize it for multiple rows. Less importantly, it does not give me the column names as the output looks like:

V1    V2         V3
1  1 Bread Automotive

Can someone help me write better code or improve this to work for multiple rows. I actually have to run for thousands of json strings like these.

Answer (score 2):

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(jsonlite)
library(daff)


df <- data.frame(
  ID  = c("1", "2", "99"),
  Product1 = c("Bread", "Butter", "err"),
  Type = c("Grocery", "Grocery", "bad"),
  Product_JSON_string = c(
    '{"ID":"1","Product1":"Bread","Type":"Automotive"}',
    '{"ID":"2","Product1":"Butter","Type":"Grocery"}',
    '{"ID":"3","Product1":"Butter","Type":"Grocery"}'
  )
)

df %>%
  select(-Product_JSON_string)
#>   ID Product1    Type
#> 1  1    Bread Grocery
#> 2  2   Butter Grocery
#> 3 99      err     bad

JSON_data <- purrr::map_df(df$Product_JSON_string, ~unlist(jsonlite::parse_json(.)))
JSON_data
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>   ID    Product1 Type      
#>   <chr> <chr>    <chr>     
#> 1 1     Bread    Automotive
#> 2 2     Butter   Grocery   
#> 3 3     Butter   Grocery

differences <- daff::diff_data(df %>%
                 select(-Product_JSON_string),
               JSON_data)
differences
#> Daff Comparison: 'df %>% select(-Product_JSON_string)' vs. 'JSON_data' 
#>     ID Product1 Type               
#> ->  1  Bread    Grocery->Automotive
#>     2  Butter   Grocery            
#> +++ 3  Butter   Grocery            
#> --- 99 err      bad

daff::render_diff(differences)
```

Comment: When I rune map_df I get the error argument 1 must be named. Not sure which argument this might be.

Comment: I have edited my answer: `map_df` belongs to the package `purrr`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `jsonlite::fromJSON` on each `Product_JSON_string` and combine the values.

```
result <- do.call(rbind, lapply(df$Product_JSON_string, function(x) 
                  as.data.frame(jsonlite::fromJSON(x))))
result

#  ID Product1       Type
#1  1    Bread Automotive
#2  2   Butter    Grocery
```

Comment: do.call(bind_rows, lapply(df$Product_json_string, function(x) 
  as.data.frame(fromJSON(minify(x))))) 

this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

just adding minify to @ronak shah's answer worked for me

do.call(bind_rows, lapply(df$Product_json_string, function(x)
as.data.frame(fromJSON(minify(x)))))